# Core Data: Traverse managed objects relationships with an abstract entity in-between

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, database-design, core-data

I have the following Core Data model, in which `ProFormaPeriod` is a subclass of the **abstract entity** `FiscalPeriod`. In my fetch request, I would like to traverse from `CalendarPeriod` to `IBEstType`.

How can I do this as `fiscalPeriod` is the only relationship I get offered in code completion and not `ProformaPeriod`.

Would I need to model an additional direct relationship from `CalendarPeriod` to `ProformaPeriod`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to fetch `FiscalPeriod` and traverse the result to check for the right class and filter out the correct IBEstType(s). It should still be quite efficient as opposed to a direct key path in the predicate, depending on the size of your data.

Otherwise, yes, you would have to make the child entity a direct relationship.

To check for the class:

```
for (NSManagedObject *obj in fetchedFiscalPeriods) { 
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[ProformaPeriod class]]) {
        ProformaPeriod *period = (ProformaPeriod*) obj;
        // check period.estimateType
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Could you please explain how it is possible to check the result of a fetch request for the right class?

Comment: I was thinking it would be possible to check for the class or entity directly in the fetch request's predicate.

Comment: Maybe that is possible, but I do not know how to traverse further down. If you want to go the predicate route, make a direct relationship (it does not cost you anything and is very efficient; also I think it also makes more sense because FiscalPeriod is abstract). -- The traversing is standard practice. It does not mean that it is fetching all the objects into memory - just the object graph, so no worries.